# How to get root back after OTA update

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-nexus, ota-update

When I updated to Android 4.1.2 on my Galaxy Nexus, I lost root. Everything is still there, but the permissions on `system/bin/su` no longer include the `setuid` bit, which prevents `su` from working.

I don't want to go through the whole re-rooting process if possible since I used root to re-lock the bootloader and unlocking it without root will wipe the entire phone, including `/storage/sdcard0`.

As far as I can tell, the only thing I need to do to get root back is to fix the permissions of `su`. How should I do this?

Of possible relevance:

- I'm using the stock ROM.
- The phone is the international GSM version.
- I tried to get into recovery and got an android with a red exclamation mark. Is this due to the bootloader being locked or is it a different problem?
- Since the update and losing root, a process called `system_service` has frequently started comsuming 100% of my CPU and slowing my phone to a crawl, forcing me to reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted doesn't seem to be possible. It makes sense, really, as if it were possible it would represent a major security hole that would allow any app to gain root.

I ended up wiping my phone and testing the quality of my backups. (They weren't as good as I'd hoped.)

Answer (score -1):

There are apps for that: Use [OTA RootKeeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.projectvoodoo.otarootkeeper) (Free) or [SuperSU Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu.pro) (Paid).

If the OTA update hasn't touched your `/system` partition, these apps will work flawlessly. Another requirement is ext2, ext3, ext4 file system. As you are with stock ROM of Galaxy Nexus, this requirement has met.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't help me as I don't have a time machine. OTA Rootkeeper couldn't do anything as it says I'm not rooted.

Comment: @Scott If you've Nandroid backup of old installation, restore that. Then, use OTA RootKeeper and do OTA update again.

Comment: Sorry. No Nandroid backup.